# SQL Escaping character for quotation mark

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the following procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateAllClients]
    @ClientIDs varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @vSQL varchar(max)
    SET @vSQL = 'UPDATE Clients SET LastOnline=GETDATE() WHERE ClientID IN (' + @ClientIDs  + ')';
    EXEC(@vSQL);
END
```

The @ClientIDs contains an array of many Client ID's, I want to update another field in the Clients table, so I want the query to look like:

```
UPDATE Clients SET LastOnline=GETDATE(), Status='Open' WHERE ClientID IN (@ClientIDs)
```

The problem is that I can put a quotation mark inside the @vSQL variable.

Any clue how can I add the ", Status='Open'" to my query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use two quotes:

```
SET @vSQL = 'UPDATE Clients SET LastOnline=GETDATE(), Status=''Open'' WHERE ClientID IN (' + @ClientIDs  + ')';
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest passing the client IDs as a table valued parameter, rather than a string. Then you can just write SQL, instead of dynamic SQL.

Comment: +1 - yes that's exactly what should be done! It is so much more efficient and it doesn't suffer from any of dynamic SQL's typical issues (that is, apart from injection and formatting issues, it also doesn't have a size restriction of 8kb for the query text size).